# Hibernate merge and update

Tags: hibernate

I have been trying to update a table row using Hibernate with no success. I have a row with values others than `null`. I want to update only the `null` values and leave the rest equal. How do I go about with this?

I am new to Hibernate and I don't want to use HQL

```
// Transaction is a parameter
// Transaction contains the values I want to update with the null columns
// but it does not contain values already saved, so the fields are null   

Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
Transaction tx = null;

try{

    tx = session.beginTransaction();

    Criteria criteria = session.createCriteria(com.business.database.Transaction.class);
    com.business.database.Transaction  savedTransaction = (com.business.database.Transaction) criteria.add(Restrictions.eq("txReference", transaction.getTxReference())).uniqueResult();

    savedTransaction = (com.business.database.Transaction) session.merge(transaction);
    session.update(savedTransaction);

    tx.commit();
    session.close(); 


    HashMap<String, Object> txMap = new HashMap<String, Object>();
    txMap.put("success", true);
    txMap.put("savedtx", savedTransaction);
    txMap.put("updatedtx", transaction);
    return txMap;

} catch (HibernateException e) {

    try {
       session.close(); 
    }  catch(Exception ex) {

    }
    System.out.println("hibernate: "+ e.getMessage());
    throw new ServiceException(ServiceStatus.FAILED_TO_UPDATE_TRANSACTION, Response.Status.BAD_REQUEST);

}
```

Comment: Transaction is the pojo class

Comment: Remove the call to merge and the call to update(), and simply update the fields you want to update in savedTransaction: `savedTransaction.setSomeField(someNewValue); savedTransaction.setSomeOtherField(someOtherNewValue);`.

Comment: I don't want to set fields, coz i will be calling this very method after several calls and should only update values that are not null in the transaction object passed, I have to make about four calls before the transaction is complete. could this be a limitation in hibernate?

Comment: You expect hibernate to implement your business logic. It won't happen. If you only want to set non-null fields, then only set non-null fields. `if (transaction.someField != null) { ... }`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I have been trying to update a table row using hibernate with no success. I have a row with values different to null and when I want to update only the null values and leave the rest.

---

**Modifying an attached object**

In Hibernate, objects attached to a session [are automatically updated](https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/5.2/userguide/html_single/Hibernate_User_Guide.html#pc-persist). If you need to change the value for some atttributes, you can set the values and the object is automatically stored in the database when you commit.

```
// 'id' is the id of the person to modify
// 'value' is the new value for a property
public void modifyPersonProperty(Integer id, String value) {
    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();

    // When you read the object from the database (even with a Criteria query).
    // it will be attached to a session.
    Person person = session.get(Person.class, id);

    // you can modify the object directly
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    person.setProperty(value);
    tx.commit();

    session.close();

}
```

---

**Replacing data with a detached object**

If you wanna replace an attached object (i.e., an object in the database) with the values in a detached object (e.g., an object created in other module or obtained from the user interface) you can use the `merge`.

The [merge method does](http://www.baeldung.com/hibernate-save-persist-update-merge-saveorupdate):

- finds an entity instance by id taken from the passed object (either an existing entity instance from the persistence context is retrieved, or a new instance loaded from the database);
- copies fields from the passed object to this instance;
- returns the newly updated instance.

For instance,

```
// 'newPerson' is the object with the new person. It has the id of the person to modify
public void modifyPerson(Person newPerson) {

    // you do not need to find the object

    Session session = SessionUtil.getSession();
    Transaction tx = session.beginTransaction();
    session.merge(newPerson);
    tx.commit();

    session.close();

}
```

Note that `merge` returns an object. You can use that object to obtain, for instance, a generated id. If you do not need to get more information, you can ignore the returned object.

---

**Detaching and attaching objects**

Hibernate has an `update` method that do not exist in other JPA implementations. If you have an object obtained from a session (i.e., an attached object), you can detach the object and re-attach it again.

```
// the original object is transient
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");

// when I store the object, it turns attached
session.save(person);

// I can use evict to detach the object
session.evict(person);

// If I change a value in the object, Hibernate will not
// update the database automatically
person.setName("Mary");

// I can attach again the object to force Hibernate to 
// update the object
session.update(person);
```

You will get an Exception if you try to `update` an object that is transient, i.e., that have been not stored or attached before to a session.

```
// When I create a Person, it is transient
Person person = new Person();
person.setName("John");

// If I wanna use update, i will get an exception
session.update(person); // PersistenceException!
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, its quiet hard to understand from the documentation, will try out your suggestion and post it here. Thanks

Comment: It seems merge attempts to create a new column and not update it

Comment: Hibernate and JPA only tries to create or modify table columns at startup if you configure it to create the database. Can you give us more information on the error messages you got?